# AddressSanitizer only finds overflow on OS X

Tags: c++, clang++, address-sanitizer

One of our developers found issues with AddressSanitizer on his machine (OS X) that were not caught by our CI (Jenkins on Linux).

Example Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    {
        std::vector<int> tmp_vec{1, 2, 3};
        tmp_vec.resize(1);
        if(tmp_vec[1] == 123) std::cout << "#1" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output on OS X with clang 6:

```
==9387==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: container-overflow on address 0x6020000000f4 at pc 0x00010fb5e4aa bp 0x7ffee00a2b90 sp 0x7ffee00a2b88
READ of size 4 at 0x6020000000f4 thread T0
    #0 0x10fb5e4a9 in main (a.out:x86_64+0x1000024a9)
    #1 0x7fff7eaa7014 in start (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x1014)
[...]
```

On Linux with clang 6, nothing happens.

Why doesn't clang on Linux catch these errors and what can we do to find these issues as part of our CI process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to mrks answer, `libstdc++` does not detect container overflow by default (as it can cause false positive warnings from Asan, check [wiki](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerClangVsGCC-(6.0-vs-8.1)) for more details). You need to enable it explicitly via `-D_GLIBCXX_SANITIZE_VECTOR` (you'll need recent enough `libstdc++`).

Comment: Even better - that was the wiki page I was looking for.

Comment: @mrks Note that there are similar wikis for older versions of GCC/Clang.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really have too much to do with the compiler or the OS. If the two machines have two different std implementations, results may vary. Explicitly setting `clang++-6.0 -stdlib=libc++ -fsanitize=address sanitizer.cpp` on the Linux machine leads to the same issues being found by ASan.

As a result, the clang builds in the CI should explicitly use `libc++`.